# How to get dropdown values of google search in arraylist using the driver.findelements()

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

When I am providing the input in google search then drop-down appears with some suggestion values I want to get those values in Arraylist to verify the drop-down values.

I am not able to understand how to get the xpath for the values when the drop down values are divided [please refer the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXDS4.png)

Comment: Find elements with `//ul[@role='listbox']//span` xpath and then get text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use <kbd>getText()</kbd> method then it till get the text from the span though you have `<b>` with in the span.

Try the below logic.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//span"));
// now you can get the text from any suggested list item
System.out.println(links.get(0).getText());
```

// or you can iterate through links and get the text from each suggestion.

Other possible locators

**CSS:**  div.suggestions-inner-container span

**xpath:** //div[@class='suggestions-inner-container']//span

===============================

**Edit 1:**

You you want to store the values in the `Set` then use the below logic.

```
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//span"));
    Set<String> resultsSet = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<links.size();i++){
          String value = links.get(i).getText();
          resultsSet.add(value);
    }
    System.out.println(resultsSet.toString());
```

Comment: Make sure to add the explicit wait for the listbox presence, otherwise your script will enter the text and fails to find the list of suggested items.

Comment: Try with the updated answer that should handle both the things mentioned in your above comments.